# How to redirect user to a Fragment within an Activity from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, back-button

1. Activity A has 4 fragments.
2. Once user clicks on a link within the 4rth fragment a webview opens up.
3. The webview has a back button.
4. Once clicked it should take user to the previous 4rth fragment of Activity A.

Is there any documentation that can help me achieve that? I am a 5 month old Android developer any help on this would be great.

I do not need the code just need to point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

do u mean activity A ,fragment 1->2->3->4 ->Activity 2 -> activity A fragment 1 ?

if so ,try this :

```
public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {

    if (fragment == null) {

        return;
    }
    // replace fragment 4 to fragment 1
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

ps. R.id.content is a frameLayout in Activity A